# GPU problem in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, gpu

I installed ubuntu on my system. But I cannot boot. I can only enter "recovery mode". I used the Safe Graphics fsection while installing. And I think the problem is my GPU. Previously, my GPU suddenly failed and my Windows was giving a blue screen. I solved this problem by disabling my GPU from device manager. But now I can't boot Ubuntu. Can you help?